# Will asynchronous JavaScript affect SEO?

Tags: seo, javascript, page-speed, load-time

As page load time affects SEO ranking. In my site I am having some asynchronous JavaScript like AddThis, Google Translator which makes my page load time longer. I want to know whether is there any adverse affect on SEO ranking. I can remove these scripts as my users are also very rarely using these.

Comment: Do you mean asynchronous or synchronous? Asynchronous JS would be faster than synchronous JS.

Answer (score 2):

Crawlers are pretty good with handling  JS now a days.

Page load times I think is more important in terms of User Experience and will effect your CTR as well many other engagement metrics which could indirectly effect your SEO.

Honestly though, I would not get too concerned with this unless there is a HUGE lag in page load. Instead focus on why people should visit your website. Do you have something on value for them? If you do, I don't think people will mind if your page load in 3 seconds instead of 2.

AddThis and Google Translate should not make your page load time THAT much longer. Have you tried running a few tests to see what the load time difference is? I would use http://webpagetest.org/ to run your tests.

Comment: They can use Chrome Developer Tools for a waterfall graph of download times. Aynchronous JavaScript will affect download times positively when a JavaScript is slow, however, if it is slow, it will remain relatively slow and still affect download speeds. Download speeds are not as important as people think. Google understands that download times vary at different times and between sites. If you are within a normal range, you are fine. Dasickle is right about user experience. Push these slow downloads to the bottom of the page and make sure you do not have a cr@pl0@d of them.